# Access Google Apps Script editor from Android

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I am searching for the answer for a couple of months now.

- Any browser redirects to downloading the Google Sheets app, which doesn't have the script editor.
- Stack Overflow redirects to a question about running script on Android, which is irrelevant.

Any information is welcome, even if you believe it to be a simple answer to a dumb question

Comment: Use the desktop page? Consider revoking the ability of the play store app to automatically handle links.

Comment: I'm able to easily open scripts in a mobile browser. Actually using the editor is different, because the pages were not designed with mobile in mind. try starting from script.google.com/home - the Apps Script dashboard

Comment: Using desktop page works randomly 1 out of 10 times, which is meh...

Answer (score 0):

The Google Apps Script editor is not designed to be used on a web browser optimized for mobile devices but some web browsers, i.e. Chrome, have an option to show the desktop version of the web site.

1. Open your web browser
2. Set it to open the webpage desktop version
3. Go to https://script.google.com
4. Open your script (project) or create a new one

Comment: I'm finding it hard to believe that any of the Commenters so far spent even 1 minute following their own advice. I'm using Chrome for Android. Impossible to scroll through your code without finding your cursor suddenly inserted somewhere in the midst of it, and your keyboard popping up, ready to edit wherever you happen to be. Selecting Desktop Site makes no difference whatsoever. Useless.

Compare this how the Sheets and Docs apps for Android have distinct Edit and View modes so that you can actually work from your phone. Is it too much to ask that Google make the same for AS?

Comment: I have been using Firefox mobile (Android version) for one month now to edit GAS (accessed with the direct link https://script.google.com indicated above). It is barely doable but feasible for light editing. Just remember to not let go the left and top margins so you can scroll up-down and left-right.