# Can I create and edit Google Sheets named functions on an iPad?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, ipad

I want to move from my MacBook Air to an iPad Pro, but I'm afraid I won't be able to get the full use of Google Sheets. I particularly need to use named functions, and also Google Apps Script.

Can I do that on an iPad, either by opening Sheets in desktop view in a browser, or in the mobile app?

Comment: If it has Google sheets app, you can use named functions, but not create it. To create, you need to use a browser with "desktop mode"

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a coding question. The question is better suited to [su]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) Google Apps Script does not work in the Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, or Forms mobile apps. In order to open the Google Apps Script in a mobile device you need to go to [script.google.com](https://script.google.com/) from the web browser of your mobile device and most likely activate the "Desktop version" of the app.

Google Apps Script is also part of the "add-ons" section of the Desktop version of Google Docs therefore as mentioned in the official documentation [add-ons are not available in iOS apps](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=0), this means that Google Apps Script is also not available through the mobile app.

Be also aware that not all Apps Script triggers and features work on the mobile apps as well. I will leave a link to a post that has a list of features that do work at the moment.

#### Referrences:

- [Use add-ons, Apps Script & AppSheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS)
- [Allow GAS Script Editor access on mobile devices through Google Drive](https://issuetracker.google.com/36765389)
- [Access Google Apps Script editor from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435112/access-google-apps-script-editor-from-android)
- [Executing Google Apps Script Functions from Mobile App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373826/executing-google-apps-script-functions-from-mobile-app)